# Create a folder on a Unix server with read-write executable permission using Java code?

Tags: java, unix

Is it possible to create a folder on a Unix server with read-write executable permission on that folder using Java code?

I have found Java example code where permissions were given only to files, not to folders.

Comment: Push comes to shove you can run a bash command using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`. But [beware the pitfalls](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html).

Comment: have you tried already?

Comment: Since a folder is a file in both Java and UNIX, I would guess you can try the same method.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#create

> You can create a new directory by using the createDirectory(Path,
>   FileAttribute) method. If you don't specify any FileAttributes, the
>   new directory will have default attributes. For example:

```
Path dir = ...; Files.createDirectory(path);
```

> The following code
>   snippet creates a new directory on a POSIX file system that has
>   specific permissions:

```
Set<PosixFilePermission> perms =
PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxr-x---"); 
FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> attr =
PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(perms); Files.createDirectory(file, attr);
```

> To create a directory several
>   levels deep when one or more of the parent directories might not yet
>   exist, you can use the convenience method, createDirectories(Path,
>   FileAttribute). As with the createDirectory(Path, FileAttribute)
>   method, you can specify an optional set of initial file attributes.
>   The following code snippet uses default attributes: